# Consuming MapServer service using ArcGIS API for Silverlight?

Tags: mapserver, arcgis-silverlight-api

Is it possible to use a service published from MapServer using ArcGIS API for Silverlight?

For example:

```
<esri:FeatureLayer ID="Schools Without Attendance Areas" 
                               MouseEnter="FeatureLayer_MouseEnter"
                               MouseLeave="FeatureLayer_MouseLeave"
                               Visible="False"
                               Url="http://webaddress"
                               OutFields="SCHNAME, ADDRESS, PHONE, URL"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Expose your data using a WMS service from Mapserver. You can then consume it as a [WMSlayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.WmsLayer.html) in the silverlight application.

Comment: Thank you for you answer .but concerning  not OGC services  , is it always possible ? Ps :  OGC services(WMS , WMTS) .

Comment: Though the Silverlight API is designed to be integrated with ArcGIS Server's REST endpoints, you can consume WMS & WMTS services in your Silverlight application

Comment: Yes ! but is it possible to consume services other than this two services , like geoprocessing service or kml service ?

Comment: @MehdiKylar That sounds like at least one new question that should be researched/asked separately.  Alternatively, more specific requirements could have been presented in the original question.